# Swagger/Swashbuckle doc: No parameter description generated for [FromUri] parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

We use Swashbuckle 5.6.0. The problem is that the auto generated swagger doc does not show descriptions for parameters when those parameters are properties of a class that is decorated with the **[FromUri]** attribute - please see screenshot.

I tried XML summary and remarks comments as well as attributes *DisplayName* and *Description* but I can't get swagger/swashbuckle to display a parameter description. (How) Can this be achieved?

[image: Missing parameter descriptions]

Method in Web API controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all folders.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="accountId">
/// Required account ID.
/// </param>
/// <param name="requestOptions">
/// The request options for the method.
/// </param>
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFoldersAsync(int accountId, [FromUri(Name = "")] GetFoldersRequestOptions requestOptions)
{
    // method content
}
```

Class *GetFoldersRequestOptions*

```
public class GetFoldersRequestOptions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary of 'Type'
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Remarks of 'Type'
    /// </remarks>
    [Description("Description of 'Type'")]
    [DisplayName("DisplayName of 'Type'")]
    public int? Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary of 'Load'
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Remarks of 'Load'
    /// </remarks>
    [Description("Description of 'Load'")]
    [DisplayName("DisplayName of 'Load'")]
    public string[] Load { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Smells like a bug...

Comment: We will see… I created an issue at GitHub but no responses so far :-/

Comment: Can you post a link to your XML documentation file

Comment: Has there been any follow up on this?